# Use a regular aggregative function (sum) alongside a window function

Tags: sql, presto

I was reading [this](http://www.wagonhq.com/blog/running-totals-sql) tutorial on how to calculate running totals.

Copying the suggested approach I have a query of the form:

```
select
    date,
    sum(sales) over (order by date rows unbounded preceding) as cumulative_sales
from sales_table;
```

This works fine and does what I want - a running total by date.

However, in addition to the running total, I'd also like to add daily sales:

```
select
    date,
    sum(sales),
    sum(sales) over (order by date rows unbounded preceding) as cumulative_sales
    from sales_table
group by 1;
```

This throws an error:

> SYNTAX_ERROR: line 6:8: '"sum"("sales") OVER (ORDER BY "activity_date" ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)' must be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause

How can I calculate both daily total as well as running total?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try it, but it will repeat your daily_sales. In this way you don't need to group by your date field.

```
SELECT date,
       SUM(sales) OVER (PARTITION BY DATE) as daily_sales
       SUM(sales) OVER (ORDER BY DATE ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as cumulative_sales
  FROM sales_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you intend an aggregation query to begin with:

```
select date, sum(sales) as daily_sales,
       sum(sum(sales)) over (order by date rows unbounded preceding) as cumulative_sales
from sales_table
group by date
order by date;
```

Comment: Just trying to understand this. You have a nested sum() there. Why? Also, is this expected to return different results from Lawrence's answer above

Comment: It looks like it returns the exact same results anyway, I just find it less readable because of the nested sum(sum())

Comment: @DougFir . . . This returns one row per date.  I have no reason to think that a sales table would have only one row per date.